# Domain for decreasing function $g(x)=2f(\frac{x^2}{2})+f(6-x^2)$

Tags: real-analysis

$g(x)=2f(\frac{x^2}{2})+f(6-x^2)$ for all $x \in R$. It is given that $f''(x)>0$ for all $x \in R$. Then find the domain for which $g(x)$ decrease.

My approach $g'(x)=2xf'(\frac{x^2}{2})-2x*f'(6-x^2)$

$g'(x)<0$

$f'(\frac{x^2}{2})<f'(6-x^2)$,  from here onward not able to approach.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

wheneven it is combination of two functions for sign
scheme of derivative it is better to make separate and combine them

Comment: Please try to give answers through writing(technically typing) as sometimes it is difficult to open pics from app. Please consider this suggestion.